# ISP issue browsing "sonos.com" - need to diagnose and prove

Tags: dns

I am unable to browse to a website "sonos.com" with my ISP (virgin). I have ruled out browsers, PCs, macs, routers, wifi, etc. Other ISPs (even other virgin connections in different areas!) supply this site no problem.

I am 99% convinced there is a DNS issue lurking here. There is something fishy about the DNS for the site : What I notice is that online DNS sites tell me the right IP address for "sonos.com", but not for "www.sonos.com".

Anyway when I type "sonos.com" (or "www.sonos.com") the browser (any/all of the 4 I tried) fails to display the page. Firefox gives a "connection was reset" error. If I browse to sonos.com using its correct IP address it works OK. Browsing to www.sonos.com or sonos.com works fine with other ISPs of course.

Questions:
1 Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?
2 Any suggestions as to tools/monitors to help investigate/prove what is going on

I can then take this up with virgin and/or sonos.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting a new [ip from virgin](http://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Wireless/Need-help-with-changing-IP-Address/td-p/811903/page/2) and replicating the issue, or at least checking your current ip isn't [blacklisted](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check)?

I've encountered this problem with websites (irritatingly my own hosting company) blacklisting virgin ips.

Comment: no, but if my ip *were* blacklisted then i don't see how i could get the page when i use the site's ip address in the browser (which definitely works)

Comment: @john Depends where and how it's implemented, there could be load balancing or language redirection in place and they are definitely using a CDN. Their www. address does have a different ip to their naked domain (which redirects to the www.) but that's probably the CDN. It's not an unusual setup, and I can't see anything suspicious about it which makes me think the problem is local. Flush your local DNS cache, check your hosts file and try a new IP (leaving your modem off overnight usually does the trick). These will likely make the problem go away.

Comment: Thanks - will do that and see if i have a different ip tomorrow and how that looks!

Comment: @john virgin support sucks on it's good days, i'd be interested to hear what happens so do come back and let us know.

Comment: Same IP address again. Modem was off for 7 hours tho. virgin support is indeed an oxymoron. I get a decent kid the other day and he pointed out that the DNS entry for "www.sonos.com" resolved to an ip address that didn't respond to web requests so it was nothing to do with Virgin - he declined to explain why *he could get the page* on his Virgin connection. Will try renewing ip and then writing some python to see what is happening. Grateful for your help on this! cheers

Comment: @john they you may need to leave it off for longer google the issue, I had to do it when this happened to me but I can't quite remember the details. I think the IP issue is more likely their CDN and url redirection than a symptom of your problem.

Comment: Hi @toomanyairmiles - I tried it again and did get a different ip but symptoms are exactly the same. I'd like to collect some trace/debug info to compare with a "good" setup (any other ISP) and my "bad" local connection - what do you think? Any other suggestions? Tools to use?

Comment: @john is this virgin media in the uk?

Comment: yes. A mate not far from me on Virgin has this page ok bith with and without www.

Comment: @john I'm using virgin media too, and have no problems seeing the page - have you checked your hosts file and eliminated anti-virus and anti spyware?

Comment: @miles. I plugged a freshly installed windows 7 laptop and also my mac directly into the cable modem and got same result. repeated since new ip address. The problem is the other side of the cable modem. As I said, I tried different OSs, browsers, wifi/enet, as direct to cable modem. Strange thing is that dns cname for "www.sonos.com" resolves to a bad ip (93.184.219.33), but except on my virgin connection this seems not to cause problems

Comment: was a virgin problem (no surprise there). network changes caused compatibility issue with older cable modems apparently. Super hub (integrated cable modem/wifi router) solved. Mystery is why it only affected sonos...